# Java FileNotFoundException even though file exists

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file located at "C:\Users\Siddharth\Documents\aarti\yeh_vidhi_mangal.txt". Following code indicates that file exists

```
String filename = "C:\\Users\\Siddharth\\Documents\\aarti\\yeh_vidhi_mangal.txt";
        File file = new File(filename);
        System.out.println(file.exists());
```

but when I try to open the file using

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
```

a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown. Is this because access is denied? I checked file permissions and they are fine.

I have also tried working without eclipse. from the command line:

> ```
>  C:\Users\Siddharth\workspace\file_io_test\src>javac Foo.java
>     Foo.java:16: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught o
>     r declared to be thrown
>                     FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
>                                          ^
>     1 error
> ```

Comment: You could move the file to C: drive and test it. "yeh_vidhi_mangal.txt" what does mean :) ?

Comment: Try getting rid of the double slashes in your path except for the C:\\

Comment: @luxun NO! that will give you an illegal escape character. :)

Comment: Are all the directory name cases correct?

Comment: 1. C:/Users/Siddharth/Documents/aarti/yeh_vidhi_mangal.txt is giving me same error 2. I tried moving the file to c:, that also does not fix it 3. I am using win7 and eclipse 4. how can i compile and execute from command line to check if its an eclipse problem?

Comment: How are u running this is code ? I mean using some IDE or from command prompt ?

Comment: @morpheus surround the statement with try-catch

Comment: See my updated answer, the code is *not* throwing that exception, it is reporting that the exception *can be* thrown and you are not accounting for this properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream%28java.io.File%29), "If the named file does not exist, is a directory rather than a regular file, **or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading** then a FileNotFoundException is thrown." (emphasis mine)  The file may be locked or in use by another application.

What does `file.canRead()` return?

---

Now that you've updated your question with more data, I can see that you are misinterpreting the error message.  The error is that you are calling a method which throws a certain type of exception and you are not properly reporting or handling the exception.  You can either add a `try` / `catch` for `FileNotFoundException` or add a `throws` to your method declaration which states that `FileNotFoundException` can be thrown.

Comment: file.canRead() is returning true.

Comment: @morpheus try luck with canExecute()

Answer (score 0):

Try using single slash rather than double slash  like

```
C:/User/Documents/your Filename.
```

and use Backward Slash Because your File is going to inherit in the following Directories so
write the path like this  for ex:

```
C:\User\Documents\Your Filename.
```

Comment: NO! this will lead to illegal escape character error :) If you want to write a \ in a String literal you have to write \\

Comment: Also, it is not necessary.  Forward slashes will work for a pathname in Java ... even on Windows; see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/316700/forward-slash-vs-back-slash-vs-file-separator-in-java